# repast symphony with google map

Tags: google-maps, shapefile, repast-simphony

I'm working with Repast-symphony trying to visualize the results of routing simulations. repast uses shape files for visualization of roads and everything else. I've looked at googlemaps api and I dont think i can get a shapefile out of their. I'm wondering

1-Is it is possible to solve this problem?( go from google map to generating a shape file directly )

2- How to develop an encoder for converting google map to shapefile?( I would like to retain the maps near there original quality)

I have seen people overlaying shape files on google map but not the other way round !

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1):

Generate a kml file from google maps using my places.  You can overlay the resulting kml on google maps.  You can also [convert kml files to shapefiles](https://www.google.com/search?q=kml+to+shapefile).

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but it won't help. when i create a kml file it only give me information about the things that i tick/routes/ but not the roads that are already in their( it simply displays them using a center coordinate and a scale ). I want to be able to take all of the data( roads, buildings, etc ) and convert them into a .shp file.

Comment: You won't be able to get that from google maps.  You will need to get the roads and buildings from a different data source.

Answer (score 0):

1- An alternative is to use http://www.openstreetmap.org/ . Shape files are directly available there for download.
2- Or you can use GIS software like QuantumGIS for example. There are some plugins that allow to convert from Google map to shape files